# Array and backreference

Tags: javascript, backreference

I'm new to backreference. I have an array and need to replace it in string.

Here's my try:

```
var cc = ["book","table"];

var str = "The $1 is on the $2";

var newstr = str.replace(cc, "$2, $1");

console.log(newstr)
```

Comment: I think you're confusing things here... `replace` expects a regex; the replacement tokens map to different capturing groups.

Comment: Convert array into string. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_array.asp

Comment: Check my answer here, that should help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371871/replacing-1-and-2-in-my-javascript-string/16371896#16371896

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's... hmm, I'm not sure I can understand the kind of confusion of ideas that would lead you to write such a thing...

Try this:

```
newstr = str.replace(/\$(\d)+/g,function(_,id) {return cc[id-1];});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var cc = ["book","table"];

var str = "The $1 is on the $2";

var newstr = str.replace('$1', cc[0]).replace('$2', cc[1]);

alert(newstr);
```